# Looking for recordings of Nina Simone solo playing piano and singing

Tags: piano

I'm interested to listen to Nina Simones piano playing, and I'm looking for songs or albums on which she plays solo, just singing and accompanying herself on piano.

Which are there (if any)?

Comment: I enjoy [Mississipi Goddam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CNwRXc9tk1s) from 1964, where she is playing piano, but is accompanied by three musicians however. (to whom she's joking during the song).

Comment: @MarcLeBihan, that's a powerful recording and I'm happy to have watched the video tonight, but I was hoping to find something where she's actually playing solo too.

Comment: [Nina Simone and Piano - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nina_Simone_and_Piano)?

Comment: @PetaspeedBeaver Answered ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I'm looking for songs or albums on which she plays solo

You can try  [Nina Simone and Piano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nina_Simone_and_Piano):

> Nina Simone and Piano! is an album by American jazz singer, songwriter, and pianist Nina Simone, with Simone accompanying herself on piano.